# how to connect "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"?

Tags: java

I have following Java code:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");  

Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.221:1433;databaseName=App91;integratedSecurity=true");  

    if(con>0)  
        out.print("You are successfully...");
```

I have included needed  jars but I still get an exception .

Comment: Still i added sqljdbc4.0 which i imported but i got an connection error

Comment: "imported"? Show what you did. Don't *tell* you got an error. Paste the error here. In full, like, keep in mind that just because you don't understand something, doesn't mean nobody understands it.

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

Comment: try{  
17:  Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");  
18:  //Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.221:1433;databaseName=App91;integratedSecurity=true");
19:  Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.221:1433;databaseName=App91;integratedSecurity=true");
20: //  jdbc:sqlserver://servername;databaseName=dbname;integratedSecurity=true
21: //   jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.221:1433/App91","root","root"
22:  if(con>0)

Comment: Stacktrace:
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:198)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:450)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:361)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)

Comment: could you push me out

Comment: This error is not a connection error. It's a compilation error. It looks like you're involving some JSP somewhere, somehow. You're going to have to show all your code, so that we get an idea what is it that doesn't compile.

Comment: Instead of adding the trace as a comment, please update your question inserting that trace. Makes things a little easier to read.